# Simplifying an Expression Further

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have a symbolic matrix given as

$$ A = 
\begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 12.5 & 12.5 k_1-5. \\
 12.5 & 12.5 k_1-5. & 2.\, -5. k_1 \\
 k_1 & 0. & 0. \\
\end{bmatrix}
 $$
when I calculate the inverse of this matrix with [Inverse](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inverse.html), I obtain the following matrix [image: picture].

The problem with this matrix is that all $10^{-15}$ should be rounded to $0$. I do this by using [Chop](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Chop.html). Basically I just use

```
Chop[expr, 10^-1]
```

which then gives me [image: picture2].

However, for example, (1,3) should just simplify to $\frac{1}{k_1}$, but I cannot achieve this with FullSimplify. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try define the matrix with exact numbers

```
a = {{0, 25/2, 25/2 k1 - 5}, {25/2, 25/2 k1 - 5, 2 - 5 k1}, {k1, 0, 0}}
```

and then

```
FullSimplify[Inverse[a]]
```

Comment: Thanks. I have a long list of expressions that lead to this result. How should I approach it so I do not have to manually define my matrix? I mean, is there something like ```format short``` for Mathematica that I can default to, if that makes sense.

Comment: you can do `FullSimplify[
 Inverse[Rationalize[{{0., 
     12.5, -5. + 12.5*k1}, {12.5, -5. + 12.5*k1, 2. - 5.*k1}, {k1, 
     0., 0.}}]]]`

Comment: Aha. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica can work with approximate numbers (as you do) or exact numbers.  Exact numbers work much better in this case

```
M = {{0, 25/2, 25/2 k - 5}, {25/2, 25/2 k - 5, 2 - 5 k}, {k, 0, 0}};

Inverse[M] // FullSimplify
(* {{0, 0, 1/k}, {4/(125 k), 2/(25 k), -(1/k^2)}, {2/(25 k), 2/(
  5 (2 - 5 k) k), 5/(k^2 (-2 + 5 k))}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks. I assume it is the fact that I have a decimal point makes the numbers approximate in my case?